# Linq To Entities, ToList() exception when called from non-UI thread

Tags: entity-framework, linq, thread-safety, linq-to-entities

I use EF 4.0 and it works really fine, however problem occured when
I call query:

---

`var query = from employee in employees
             from cr in employee.RcpCrossRegister
select new { employee, cr }`

then when I call

```
var list = query.ToList()
```

I got exception

```
    Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute
and call stack: 

       w System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   w System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
   w System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   w System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.CheckIfNavigationPropertyContainsEntity(IEntityWrapper wrapper)
   w System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Add(IEntityWrapper wrappedTarget, Boolean applyConstraints, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean allowModifyingOtherEndOfRelationship, Boolean forceForeignKeyChanges)
   w System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Add(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean applyConstraints)
   w System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.set_ReferenceValue(IEntityWrapper value)
   w System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference.SetEntityKey(EntityKey value, Boolean forceFixup)
   w System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.FixupEntityReferenceToPrincipal(EntityReference relatedEnd, EntityKey foreignKey, Boolean setIsLoaded, Boolean replaceExistingRef)
   w System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.FixupReferencesByForeignKeys(Boolean replaceAddedRefs)
   w System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.FixupReferencesByForeignKeys(EntityEntry newEntry, Boolean replaceAddedRefs)
   w System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddEntry(IEntityWrapper wrappedObject, EntityKey passedKey, EntitySet entitySet, String argumentName, Boolean isAdded)
   w System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
   w lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   w System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
   w System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
   w TCS.bos.Infrastructure.Data.MainModule.Repositories.EmployeeRepository.GetEmployeesEvacuationTimeSheet(Int64 dateHour)
   w TCS.bos.Domain.MainModule.Employees.EmployeeTimeSheetService.GetEmployeesEvacuationTimeSheet(Int64 dateHour)
   w TCS.plg.TimeSheets.ViewModels.TimeSheetsGridViewModel.GetAll2()
   w TCS.plg.TimeSheets.ViewModels.TimeSheetsGridViewModel.<>c__DisplayClass4.<FilterCommand>b__2()
   w TCS.Core.Caliburn.Invocation.BackgroundTask.<>c__DisplayClassd.<.ctor>b__4(Object s, DoWorkEventArgs e) w D:\VS2010\CaliburnMicro\caliburnmicro_a63379fba70a\TCS.2.3\TCS.Core\Caliburn\Invocation\BackgroundTask.cs:wiersz 41
   w System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
   w System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
```

Comment: What do you do between creating the query and enumerating it? It's deferred, so anything you do before won't happen until you try to enumerate.

Comment: you are right, but that's exactly the code I use  ...

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework is not thread-safe, you can only use an `ObjectContext` on the thread that created it.

Comment: ... important note: this exception occur only when called from non-UI thread... I suspect
that 'Relational fix-up' makes some work on collection and that cause exception but no idea
how to fix it ...

----------
I don't have any problems when I call it from UI thread but I need to show progress bar on UI thread ....

Comment: It works on the UI thread because you probably created the ObjectContext on the UI thread...

Comment: @Thomas Levesque: "is not thread-safe" is not equal "can only be used on the thread that created it". Can you see the difference?

Comment: @zespri, yes, I know the difference, but I didn't mention it in my answer for the sake of simplicity. Anyway, every time I tried to manipulate an ObjectContext from another thread than the one on which it was created, I ran into similar issues.

Comment: when I call simple query "from employee in employees select employee" and then ToList() it works fine so the theory about 'Relational fix-up' seems to be true ...